# How to replace a 1 or more charceters in string with other characters?

Tags: java, string

I need to print

```
......e......                
..e..........                
........e....                


.....iAi.....
```

where e is and enemy with a position, so i have replace a dot with changing position, with 0 being the center boundaries -6 and 6 on the left and right respectively. and the iAi is the player with 2 gun so i have to replace 3 "." with 2 i and 1 A 
what i have so far for the enimes is

```
String asd = ".............";
    char cas;
    if ((isDead()== true)|| (justHit=true))
    cas = 'x';
    else 
    cas ='e';
    String wasd = asd.substring(0,position-1)+cas+asd.substring(position +1);
    return wasd;
```

but it isn't replacing in the right place

Comment: First thing first `(justHit=true)` should be `(justHit==true)`

Comment: @Prateek, better yet simply `justHit`.

Comment: yeah, but I wanted to point out his typo

Comment: What about `char[][] gamearea`?

Comment: How are you calculating position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, maybe it will help

```
    String s1 = ".............";
    String s2 = "xx";
    int p = 1;
    String s3 = s1.substring(0, p)  + s2 + s1.substring(p + s2.length());
    System.out.println(s1);
    System.out.println(s3);
```

output

```
.............
.xx..........
```

Comment: what about the the player "iAi"

Answer (score 1):

Using a String means to recreate an amount of Objects in every loop. Using char[] should significantly lower the footprint:

```
    private char[] afd = {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'};
    private int prevPos = 0;

    public String placeEnemy(int newPos, boolean dead, boolean justHit) {
        afd[prevPos] = '.';
        afd[newPos] = 'e';
        prevPos = newPos;
        return afd
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `asd.substring(0, position)` instead of `asd.substring(0, position - 1)` in your code above.